# How does dual wielding work?

Tags: runescape

Apparently, with the new Evolution of Combat update, Runescape now includes the ability to dual wield weapons. However, I have not yet figured out how to accomplish this.

So, what weapons can I wield in the off-hand (shield) slot and how can I equip them that way? Is there any other way it is different from normal combat besides just having another weapon instead of a shield?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to fight with dual-wielded weapons is by equipping a normal one-hand weapon in the main weapon slot and an "offhand" weapon in the offhand/shield slot. These offhand weapons are separate items from the regular weapons, each corresponding to an existing one-hand weapon. Each offhand weapon can be obtained in the same way as its corresponding regular weapon.

Almost every one-hand weapon has a corresponding offhand weapon. A notable exception is the Abyssal Whip, which apparently had animation issues. One other oddity is that dragon claws, previously two-hand weapons, are now separately obtainable as claw and off-hand claw.

As far as I can tell, the only real difference that comes from the extra weapon is the extra DPS.

Almost all of this information comes from [this reddit thread I posted](http://www.reddit.com/r/runescape/comments/13zplp/does_anyone_here_know_how_dual_wielding_works_the/).

Answer (score 0):

You seen what is called a "defender" in the off-hand,not a sword. You can obtain a "defender" by obtaining the appropriate (str) & (att) stats to equal 130 combined points to enter the warriors guild.( you can get here by using a combat bracelet) There are two mini games in which you obtain "warrior guild tokens" to use to obtain the " defenders" 100 guild tokens grants you access to the top and bottom floors to obtain the defenders. Top floor contains lower level "Cyclops" in which you can obtain bronze to rune defenders. Bottom floor resides higher level "Cyclops" in which you can kill to obtain the dragpn defenderwhich has stats comparable to an adamant kite w/
attack bonuses as well as a +6 strength bonus.

Comment: This appears to be describing how the system works in Old School Runescape, but the question is about how the system works after the Evolution of Combat update in Runescape.

Answer (score -4):

Currently it is not possibly to duel wield weapons, only tuna.

Comment: I know this is not accurate, since I saw someone wielding a whip and a sword.